# Dependencies waiting to be satisifed

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, castle-windsor, s#arp-architecture

I'm trying to abstract some simple tasks for some very simple objects.

In my domain model, there are a number of different objects which basically serve as a way to tag (classify) a "Program." The Business Logic says a program can have as many of these as its wants, but no tags of the same type (e.g., "County") can have the same name, and you can't delete a tag while it has programs linked to it.

This is built on MVC3 with S#arp 2.0.

The domain model has an abstract base class `NamedEntity : Entity` which defines 
`public string Name { get; set; }`
among other properties.

Specific types extend this class to add whatever makes them unique (if anything), such as Topic, which is a heirarchical structure and so has additional properties for that.

I wanted to create `INamedEntityTasks<T> where T: NamedEntity` and then have a base version of this for handling routine tasks like `bool CheckForDuplicateName(string Name)` which would run access its `INamedEntityQueries<T>` object and call `T FindByName(string Name)`

If a subclass needed to add more rules prior to delete (e.g. a topic with children can't be deleted), then it just overrides the virtual method from the base class.

Structure:

- `MyProject.Infrastructure` has `INamedEntityQueries<T>` and `NamedEntityQueries<T>` as well as `ITopicQueries : INamedEntityQueries<Topic>` and `TopicQueries: NamedEntityQueries<T>, ITopicQueries`
- `MyProject.Domain.Contracts.Tasks` has `INamedEntityTasks<T>` and `ITopicTasks : INamedEntityTasks<Topic>`
- `MyProject.Tasks` has `NamedEntityTasks<T>` and `TopicTasks: NamedEntityTasks<Topic>, ITopicTasks`

My `TopicsController` won't run because of a **missing dependency** that I can't figure out.

The exact exception is

> Can't create component
>   'MyProject.web.mvc.controllers.topicscontroller'
>   as it has dependencies to be
>   satisfied. 
>   MyProject.web.mvc.controllers.topicscontroller
>   is waiting for the following
>   dependencies:
>
> Services: 
>   - MyProject.Infrastructure.Queries.ITopicQueries
>   which was not registered. 
>   - MyProject.Domain.Contracts.Tasks.ITopicTasks
>   which was registered but is also
>   waiting for dependencies.
>
> MyProject.Tasks.TopicTasks is waiting
>   for the following dependencies:
>
> Services: 
>   - MyProject.Infrastructure.Queries.INamedEntityQueries`1[[MyProject.Domain.Topic,
>   MyProject.Domain, Version=1.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]]
>   which was not registered.

I checked the `container` in `ComponentRegistrar` with a breakpoint and it shows 3 potentially misconfigured:

```
"MyProject.Tasks.NamedEntityTasks`1" NamedEntityTasks`1
"MyProject.Tasks.TopicTasks" ITopicTasks / TopicTasks
"MyProject.web.mvc.controllers.topicscontroller" TopicsController`TopicsController`
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: question is pretty long... can you narrow it down? or ideally, just provide a failing test?

Comment: My test project won't currently load...

MyProject.Tests.MyProject.Tasks.CategoryTasksTests.CanConfirmDeleteReadiness:
SetUp : System.NullReferenceException : ServiceLocator has not been initialized; I was trying to retrieve SharpArch.NHibernate.ISessionFactoryKeyProvider
  ----> System.NullReferenceException : Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: @Carl: you could create another question specifically for that

Comment: To narrow the question down:
If you have abstract class Foo, and subclasses FooBar and FooBaz, which differ only slightly, is it possible and advisable to write Tasks which operate on Foos by defining an interface `IFooTasks<T> where T : Foo` and implementing this, then defining interfaces `IFooBarTasks : IFooTasks<FooBar>` (etc) and implementing these? 

If this is possible, how do you get Castle Windsor to play nicely with all this?

Comment: New question created... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6473728/servicelocator-not-initialized-in-tests-project

Comment: I have cut the question down as much as I can without eliminating what I think is essential data. See also the comment above this one for a very high-level summary of what I'm trying to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need the IFooTasks interface, just use an abstract base class, then IFooBarTasks and IFooBazTasks will be registered with Castle Windsor by the standard ComponentRegistrar in S#arp Architecture:

```
public abstract class Foo
{
  public void Foo1();

  public void Foo2();
}

public class FooBar : Foo
{
  public void FooBar1();
}

public class FooBaz : Foo
{
  public void FooBaz1();
}

public interface IFooTasks
{
  void Foo1();

  void Foo2();
}

public interface IFooBarTasks : IFooTasks
{
  void FooBar1();
}

public interface IFooBazTasks : IFooTasks
{
  void FooBaz1();
}

public abstract class FooTasks : IFooTasks
{
  public void Foo1()
  {
    // Foo1 implementation
  }

  public void Foo2()
  {
    // Foo2 implementation
  }
}

public class FooBarTasks : FooTasks, IFooBarTasks
{
  public void FooBar1()
  {
    // FooBar1 implementation
  }
}

public class FooBazTasks : FooTasks, IFooBazTasks
{
  public void FooBaz1()
  {
    // FooBaz1 implementation
  }
}
```

Comment: That's almost exactly what I had, except my base tasks/queries were not abstract. I made them abstract and I still get an error that MyProject.Tasks.TopicTasks is waiting for the following dependencies:  MyProject.Infrastructure.Queries.ITopicQueries which was not registered.

Comment: In my unit test: 
`private ITopicTasks topicTasks = new TopicTasks(new NHibernateRepository<Topic>(), new TopicQueries());`

In TopicTasks.cs

`public TopicTasks(INHibernateRepository<Topic> topicRepository, ITopicQueries neQueries) : base(topicRepository, neQueries)
        {
        
        }`

Comment: Sounds like TopicTasks is being created via Windsor rather than your code:  
  
  `private ITopicTasks topicTasks = new TopicTasks(new NHibernateRepository<Topic>(), new TopicQueries());`

Comment: Right, the test isn't the problem actually, I should have grabbed the controller code: 
`public TopicsController(ITopicQueries topicQueries, ITopicTasks topicTasks)`

That's the one that's not working.

Comment: The AddQueryObjectsTo method in ComponentRegistrar will register every interface and implementation in your Web / Presentation project, are your query interfaces and implementations in this project?

Comment: @ChrisR, I put the query interfaces in the `Infrastructure` project (because if the the Tasks layer needs to call the queries and the Web project needs to call the Tasks, then the queries can't live in the Web project) and modified ComponentRegistrar
`container.Register(AllTypes.FromAssemblyNamed("MyProject.Web.Mvc")                    .Pick().WithService.FirstInterface());

container.Register(AllTypes.FromAssemblyNamed("MyProject.Infrastructure").Pick().WithService.DefaultInterface());`

Comment: With Sharp Architecture 2.0 two types of query are supported: enhanced query objects should live in the Web layer and should only be concerned with projecting data directly into your view models, the other queries derive from SharpArch.Domain.PersistenceSupport.IQuery<> and should only be used for common queries required within your domain. Have you taken a look at the cookbook [link](https://github.com/sharparchitecture/Sharp-Architecture-Cookbook/wiki)

Comment: I've looked at the cookbook and decided without better documentation for why things were in a certain place, I wasn't going to make much sense of it. I'll try taking another look at it. My queries are things like "Find an entity by its name" (so we can check that you're not going to duplicate a name with a new entity; these are small tables so performance is not an issue) or "Find the top-level objects in this hierarchy"... the latter is definitely presentational, so I could see that being in the Web, but the former is related to business logic.

Comment: For business logic queries, the interface should be declared in the Domain project and in the Contracts.Queries namespace, and the implementation should be in the Infrastructure.Queries namespace. 
For the enhanced query objects the interface and implementation should both be in the Web project.

Comment: To see whether this is solely a Windsor registration issue, you could explicitly register the ITopicQuery and see if that works:    

`container.Register(
     Component.For(typeof(ITopicQuery))
     .ImplementedBy(typeof(TopicQuery))
     .Named("TopicQuery"));`

Comment: Actually that did the trick. My controller will now run and everything looks correct. My controller calls the function GetTopLevelTopics within TopicQueries so that at least is wired up correctly.

Comment: OK, so it is a Windsor registration problem. You said the query interfaces are in the Infrastructure project, where are the implementations? Try changing your original code in ComponentRegistrar to use FirstInterface instead of DefaultInterface for the registrations from the Infrastructure project.

Comment: I refactored to match the Cookbook a little better (although I'm fuzzy on some points)... Presentational Queries (ITopicQueries) and interfaces both in Web.Mvc.Controllers.Queries ; Functional Queries (INamedEntityQueries<T>) have interfaces in Domain.Contracts.Queries and implementations in Infrastructure.Queries. I intend to change this back, because it seems overly complicated to me to make the separation between the types of queries, especially when the query classes have inheritance.
In this setup, .AllInterfaces for both Web and Infrastructure works. Drawbacks to AllInterfaces?

Comment: Argh. When I refactor to put all query interfaces in Domain and all implementations in Infrastructure, it breaks again, complaining about INamedEntityQueries<T>.

Comment: Aren't we know back to a similar position as at the beginning of this answer? You don't need the interface INamedEntityQueries, just use an abstract base class.

Comment: But then all my interfaces that define "These are the queries you can do to a Topic", "...to a Category", "...to a City" would all have to declare those methods? Slightly redundant. If I have 10 different types of NamedEntities and I might want to find any of them by its Name property (defined in NamedEntity), it seems I want a "base" interface telling me I can do that (and a base class to do it).

Comment: OK, keep the interface but you do not need to register it and don't take a dependency on it, use the derived interfaces instead.

Comment: With some additional help from Alec on the S#arp mailing list, we got this working. Alec had me explicitly register INamedEntityRepository<> with Castle Windsor, and that seemed to clear up most of the problems I was having.