# ServiceLocator not initialized in Tests project

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, nunit, s#arp-architecture

When attempting to write a test related to my new Tasks (MVC3, S#arp 2.0), I get this error when I try to run the test:

> MyProject.Tests.MyProject.Tasks.CategoryTasksTests.CanConfirmDeleteReadiness:
>   SetUp : System.NullReferenceException
>   : ServiceLocator has not been
>   initialized; I was trying to retrieve
>   SharpArch.NHibernate.ISessionFactoryKeyProvider
>   ----> System.NullReferenceException : Object reference not set to an
>   instance of an object.
>
> at
>   SharpArch.Domain.SafeServiceLocator`1.GetService()
>   at
>   SharpArch.NHibernate.SessionFactoryKeyHelper.GetKeyFrom(Object
>   anObject) at
>   SharpArch.NHibernate.NHibernateRepositoryWithTypedId`2.get_Session()
>   at
>   SharpArch.NHibernate.NHibernateRepositoryWithTypedId`2.Save(T
>   entity) at
>   MyProject.Tests.MyProject.Tasks.CategoryTasksTests.Setup()
>   in
>   C:\code\MyProject\Solutions\MyProject.Tests\MyProject.Tasks\CategoryTasksTests.cs:line
>   36
>   --NullReferenceException at Microsoft.Practices.ServiceLocation.ServiceLocator.get_Current()
>   at
>   SharpArch.Domain.SafeServiceLocator`1.GetService()

Other tests which do not involve the new class (e.g., generate/confirm database mappings) run correctly.

My ServiceLocatorInitializer is as follows

```
public class ServiceLocatorInitializer
{

public static void Init() 
{
    IWindsorContainer container = new WindsorContainer();

        container.Register(
                Component
                    .For(typeof(DefaultSessionFactoryKeyProvider))
                    .ImplementedBy(typeof(DefaultSessionFactoryKeyProvider))
                    .Named("sessionFactoryKeyProvider"));

    container.Register(
            Component
                .For(typeof(IEntityDuplicateChecker))
                .ImplementedBy(typeof(EntityDuplicateChecker))
                .Named("entityDuplicateChecker"));

    ServiceLocator.SetLocatorProvider(() => new WindsorServiceLocator(container));
}
}
```

Comment: are you calling ServiceLocatorInitializer.Init() anywhere in your test? Or ServiceLocator.SetLocatorProvider() ?

Comment: Hm, I thought I copied from a working test class, but there's a chance I just added a new class and coded by hand... I'll have to check after the weekend.

Comment: I added an explicit call to Init and changed the type line as hinted below, but we're not out of the woods yet.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are registering DefaultSessionFactoryKeyProvider as an implementation of DefaultSessionFactoryKeyProvider, while you have a dependency on ISessionFactoryKeyProvider, which castle windsor doesn't know how to resolve as no implementations has been registered for that interface.

I think that should be:

container.Register(
                Component
                    .For(typeof(ISessionFactoryKeyProvider))
                    .ImplementedBy(typeof(DefaultSessionFactoryKeyProvider))
                    .Named("sessionFactoryKeyProvider"));

Comment: That definitely helped, but now I have:
`MyProject.Tests.MyProject.Tasks.CategoryTasksTests.CanConfirmDeleteReadiness:
SetUp : System.TypeLoadException : Could not load type 'Castle.Core.Resource.FileResourceFactory' from assembly 'Castle.Core, Version=2.5.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=407dd0808d44fbdc'.`

Comment: Since this answered the problem directly asked about by the question, I have to accept this as the answer. Special thanks also to @ChrisR who helped immensely and created a nice demo (see below).

Answer (score 2):

Is Castle.Core referenced by your test project?

Comment: Castle.Core and Castle.Windsor are both referenced.

Comment: FileResourceFactory is in the Castle.Core assembly, so the assembly  is either not referenced or you are referencing an incorrect version.

Comment: I removed the reference and did `install-package Castle.Windsor` which seems to have fixed that.

Comment: This leads to 
`SetUp : SharpArch.Domain.PreconditionException : An ISessionStorage has not been configured`

Comment: That is initialised by the call to InitialiseNHibernateSessions in the Application_BeginRequest method in GlobalAsax.cs

Comment: That exists and works on the web end (or did, before I broke everything with my abstract classes, see other questions). A breakpoint there is hit when I run the web project as my startup, but not when I start the test project (invoking NUnit as the debug action for it so NUnit is started directly). Not sure what that says... I've never really thought about what happens in global.asax when you're not running the web project as the default.

Comment: When running your unit tests, the code in GlobalAsax.cs will not be called. Does your test fixture derive from `RepositoryTestsBase` or `DatabaseRepositoryTestsBase` ? The Setup and Teardown methods in these classes initialise NHibernate for you.

Comment: Getting there. Added the inheritance (my other unit tests were to generate and confirm the DB mapping which worked, and didn't have the inheritance). 

Now we can't configure the database... if you step through about 4 levels of InnerException, it eventually complains that it can't find the dialect. 

"{"Could not find the dialect in the configuration"}"

Which is odd because as noted, other unit tests in the same project can and do talk to the DB (Sqlite)

Comment: Of course, that would be a completely different DB context (a MSSQL server) not the SQLite, but I look at the config in the test project and see `<property name="dialect">NHibernate.Dialect.SQLiteDialect</property>`

Comment: Make sure that the Hibernate.cfg.xml file in your tests project  is copied to the output directory => select the file in Solution Explorer, right click and select Properties, and then set the 'Copy to Output Directory' property to 'Copy if newer'

Comment: Checked that earlier (it was set Do Not Copy, but neither Copy Always nor 'Newer' make a difference).

Comment: See https://github.com/yellowfeather/TestSA2 for a sample project with a working unit test